# Share webpages between multiple websites (Best Way)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, web

I have created two websites using C# in Visual studio 2008. Both websites having common maintenance (User and Role) pages. I have also create a common class library (C#) and added reference to both website, which is working properly.

I don't want to replicate/maintain the multiple copies of the same aspx pages.

Is there any better way except user controls, to have single copy of common aspx pages and add reference to both website, just like class library?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with multiple copies as long as you have a single copy in your source control and both projects are sharing it.

Comment: Can anyone suggest the link, incase of master page or user control?

Answer (score 0):

In your response to Mr.Lister it sounds like you aren't using a [master page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), and your really should.